# Oracle SQL match string with left zeros padding

Tags: oracle11g, padding, trim

I have to find strings which can or cannot starts with zeros.
For instance, if I have in my db the values '00563', '563', '43563', '0563', I have to find the rows '00563', '563', '0563'.

I've tryed this:

```
select distinct val
from table_one
where val = '00563' OR 
      val = ltrim('00563', '0');
```

but doesn't work.
val is a CHAR(5 BYTE) column.

Can you help me?

EDIT:
To be precise, if I execute the query:

```
select distinct val
from table_one;
```

the result is:

```
5034 
(null)
4dsfd
01005
03030
03075
05034
```

To me, 05034 and 5034 are the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the column value and the literal value you're searching for match - explicitly making them the same data type (and length).

An earlier version of this answer gave various permutations based on unknowns and assumptions, but summarising comments: your `val` column is defined as `char(5)` (so the values are space-padded, which will have to be taken into account), may have values that can't be converted to numbers, and the value (literal or variable) you're comparing against is a number. Based on all of that most of the variations aren't relevant to you, and you can do:

```
select distinct val
from table_one
where lpad(trim(val), 5, '0') = lpad(to_char(563), 5, '0');
```

The `val` from the table column is trimmed to remove whitespace (because it's `char`), then padded with zeros up to the maximum length instead. The number you're comparing against is converted to a string and also zero-padded to the same length. Those two strings can then be compared.

With some sample data:

```
create table table_one(val char(5));
insert into table_one
  select '00563' from dual
  union all select '563' from dual
  union all select '43563' from dual
  union all select '0563' from dual
  union all select '09999' from dual
  union all select '4dsfd' from dual;

select distinct val
from table_one
where lpad(trim(val), 5, '0') = lpad(to_char(563), 5, '0');

VAL  
-----
00563
0563 
563
```

Applying a function to the table column value will prevent any index on that column being used, but that doesn't seem to be avoidable unless you can clean up the data in your table.

Comment: In the first code snippet, `ltrim('00563', '0')` is simply the literal `'563'`, not sure why `ltrim()` is needed for a literal. You probably meant '563' may be a variable of some sort (such as a bind variable) - in which case it is not a literal. Then, even if this variable is a number, in the second code snippet it is better to convert it explicitly to string, perhaps with `to_char()`. Finally, there is no point in having `val` by itself on the LHS if you still need to wrap it within a function call on the RHS; you will still be unable to use an index because of that.

Comment: The OP shows a zero-padded literal, so I've started with that as worst-case. Yes, I kind of assume they may really have a variable, which may be a zero-padded string, but I've shown the equivalent if they have or can have a number instead. Showing a different string literal to the question doesn't seem useful though. (The second one would implicitly convert the trimmed LHS to number to compare; I've added yet another that converts RHS to string instead.).

Comment: The value of val has to be a 5 char number with zeros if the value is too short. However I've to take that value from a service which consider val as number and remove the initial 0. Unfortunately this is incorrect but the old datas now are stored on db and I need to find even the values without 0.

Comment: I've tried the various versions without success, with error like "invalid number".
Can the problem be that the are incorrect values stored in the db, like null or '4dsfd'?

Comment: @DeooK - only the 2ns, 4th and 5th should variations be capable of giving you that error, unless there are other conditions you aren't showing us. With implicit or explicit conversion of `val` to a number, you will get that error with value that can't be converted, as I mentioned in my answer. The others should be working though.

Comment: The first query give me only the result with 0 at the beginning.
I cannot use the second query because the value is not already a number.
The third query give me no results.
The fourth query give me the error "invalid number".
For the fifth are valid the same considerations applied to the second.
For the others are valid the same considerations applied to the first.
In the first post I've inserted the list of the values that I've in the db.

Comment: What is the data type of the `val` column? I'm not sure I follow your last comment, but it sounds like maybe it's `char(5)` rather than `varchar2(5)`? Maybe add the DDL for that to the question too.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot alter the table or remove wrong values, but the last query works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the values you have provided. I guess your values will have maximum 3 numbers before it gets padded. Keeping that in mind you can try this out -

```
select distinct val from table_one where regexp_like(val,'^0*[0-9]{1,4}$');
```

Comment: Not exactly: if the value is '1', I have to find '1', '01', '001', '0001' and '00001'.
The max lenght is 5.

Comment: Okay if max length is 5 then the above query will work.

Comment: With that query I found all the values starting with 0.